# Convert links of downloaded website

Tags: wget

I downloaded a website using:

```
wget -c --mirror -p http://www.somewebsite.com
```

for offline viewing and I just remembered that I forgot the --convert-links option! They are all on my hard drive right now. Is there a way to do --convert-links without redownloading the whole website?

Answer (score 10):

Straightforward one: serve local directory with something like [SimpleHTTPServer](http://docs.python.org/library/simplehttpserver.html), then re-`wget` from localhost with appropriate options.

Comment: Quite a good idea, why the down vote?

Comment: I should add that one shout edit `/etc/hosts` to fake localhost as the website being mirrored. And this will only work well if the links all point to the same webpage (i.e no hot-linked images).

Comment: What is SimpleHTTPServer? Is it the Python module? If so, can you show how to use it (so I can revoke my careless downvote).

Comment: @Tshepang Yes Python is pretty awesome with the huge load of modules :) SimpleHTTPServer is [my favorite](http://phunehehe.isgreat.org/2011/file-sharing-with-pythons-built-in-http-server/)

Comment: @phunehehe That's very clever. If the local files link to remote files, I don't think the answer would work without your idea. As long as you have downloaded the remote files locally, your idea will work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Also, don't forget to use the option `--timestamping`, or add `timestamping=on` to "**~/.wgetrc**". It ensures that when you re-mirror the website, you don't re-download the whole website, but only changed/new files. See the section **Time-Stamping** in manpage of wget for more.

FWIW I use this to mirror my blog:

> wget --mirror --adjust-extension --convert-links --no-cookies --timestamping http://example.com --output-file=log-blog