# wget: --convert-links in already-downloaded folder?

Tags: wget, download

Is there a way to separate `wget`'s download and `--convert-links` functionality? For those unfamiliar with `wget` and/or `--convert-links`, long story short, wget can be used to download a website. `--convert-links` modifies the downloaded html files so the downloaded website works off-line. It does that by converting the `href`/`src`/etc. attributes to reference local files instead of the remote website.

This is the [official explanation](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Retrieval-Options.html):

> -k
> --convert-links
>
> After the download is complete, convert the links in the document to make them suitable for local viewing.  This affects not
> only the visible hyperlinks, but any part of the document that links
> to external content, such as embedded images, links to style
> sheets, hyperlinks to non-HTML content, etc.
>
> Each link will be changed in one of the two ways:
>
> •   The links to files that have been downloaded by Wget will be changed to refer to the file they point to as a relative link.
>
> Example: if the downloaded file /foo/doc.html links to /bar/img.gif, also downloaded, then the link in doc.html will be
> modified to point to ../bar/img.gif.  This kind of transformation
> works reliably for arbitrary combinations of directories.
>
> •   The links to files that have not been downloaded by Wget will be changed to include host name and absolute path of the
> location they point to.
>
> Example: if the downloaded file /foo/doc.html links to /bar/img.gif (or to ../bar/img.gif), then the link in doc.html will be
> modified to point to http://hostname/bar/img.gif.
>
> Because of this, local browsing works reliably: if a linked file was downloaded, the link will refer to its local name; if it was
> not downloaded, the link will refer to its full Internet address
> rather than presenting a broken link.  The fact that the
> former links are converted to relative links ensures that you can move the downloaded hierarchy to another directory.
>
> Note that only at the end of the download can Wget know which links have been downloaded.  Because of that, the work done by
> -k will be performed at the end of all the downloads.

If a (recursive) download gets interrupted & resumed manually, or if one fails to specify `-k` to begin with, how can one get sane links inside the `html` files?

It seems not even `--backup-converted` can make the process more robust, as either wget converts links right after downloading *everything* (no missing files), or you're on your own (xpath etc)

Answer (score 2):

Since `.html` files are ASCII text, you can post-process the `.html` files, with `sed`. Files containing, for example `http://bad.url/good.part` and `https://bad.url/good.part` and should have `good.url` instead, leaving the unmodified `*.html` files as `*.html.bak`.

```
find . -type f -name '*.html' -print0 | \
  xargs -0 -r sed -i.bak -e 's%://bad\.url/%://good.url/%'
```

Naturally, read `man find xargs sed`

Comment: I found a completely different answer to this question here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/7378/101311 Your answer seems far simpler than theirs, and my **gut** tells me the complexity is there for a good reason. Like, there might be edge cases where your solution doesn't work? Any idea why nobody else has thought of such a simple answer before you?

Comment: @DanielKaplan "complexity" increases the bug surface, unnecessarily. Set up a local webserver, lie to `/etc/hosts`, re-transfer all the files, oh and remember the `--timestamping` option. Remember to undo all of this when you're done? Just to change text in an ASCII file? My "solution" has been known among the Unix/Linux community since the beginning. I regard  it as a well-known general algorithm applied to a specific case. Which "edge cases:? That's why I leave the `.bak` files behind. `diff` to check changes. You can adjust the match string to get the results you want.

Comment: "Which "edge cases:?" Well, for example, what if a link starts with a `/` instead of having a `bad.url`?

Comment: @DanielKaplan In that case, the script would need to detect that and adapt. Why not look at how wget does it?

Comment: @9pfssupportsUkraine That's a fair question. I assumed I wouldn't be able to find the logic or understand it. The last time I read C code was a decade ago and I never knew how to program specifically for linux. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @DanielKaplan C is basically just JavaScript with additional types for data.

Comment: @9pfssupportsUkraine http://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/lh/wget/trunk/view/head:/src/convert.c Looks like the logic is ~1000 lines. I may look into it later, but it might take considerable effort to translate/extract what I'm looking for.

Comment: @DanielKaplan Why not compile it to WebAssembly and run it with nodejs without analyzing it at all?

Comment: @9pfssupportsUkraine Great idea! Then I'd have the same problem, but in web assembly.

Comment: But you could then create a program using the `pkg` package that'd do what you want, _and_ avoid analyzing the source!

Comment: Unconverted URLs can contain relative paths (`../x.html`), absolute paths (`/x.html`), and URL links. Relative paths also get affected by `<base>`. This is nasty, and that's the whole point of the question. As the ending says, "or you're on your own (xpath etc)" -- thanks for proposing a downgrade from xpath to sed :)

Comment: I mean no personal offense, but after sleeping on it, I agree with @usretc. In context, this should be a comment. The majority of the answer is an exercise left to the reader. In addition, usretc points out this answer doesn't even work in a lot of situations. For these reasons, I've flagged it as "not an answer."

Comment: @DanielKaplan you may find the opinions vary on this, but IMHO, waltinator's Answer here is an *attempt to answer the question*. I can't speak to the validity of the answer (as I don't personally understand the question), but I would reserve "NAA" for things that are obviously further questions or comments that belong under another post instead of as an Answer.

Comment: @JeffSchaller In an attempt to clarify the question, I have suggested an edit to the original post. Hope that helps. re: `I would reserve "NAA" for ... comments that belong under another post instead of as an Answer.` I was thinking it falls under this, but I suppose it could be edited further to make it complete; as it stands, there are myriad examples -- `href`s in the original that start with `/`, `../`, and `./` -- where this falls short of `--convert-links` functionality.

Comment: Thank you, @DanielKaplan. Again, it's a bit of a range in my experience, but *attempts* to answer the question, even if they fall short, can stand as Answers where others can comment on the limitations of the answer or even edit it to improve it. I personally reserve "NAA" for answers that say "thanks" to another answer or "I have this *other* problem...".

Comment: @JeffSchaller makes sense, thanks.